# htaccess on codeigniter in the website

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi i have problems in the url .. i think the htaccess code when i uploaded my file to the live website i notice that the error is thi -------------->No input file specified. here is my link to the website  http://springrainglobal.com/movies_world/index.php/movies 
here is my htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|images|js|assets|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /movies_world/index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /movies_world/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

can anyone help me out on how to configure properly the htacces on live server?pls help

Comment: Are you sure the problem is htaccess? (it's probably not) Can you post the controller and view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your site is available under http://springrainglobal.com/movies_world/movies (leave the index.php), if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: wow great! thanks for your help men! it helps a lot in me! i didnt think that index.php should not be place! thanks! it works!

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard .htaccess I always use for CodeIgniter builds:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

If you change line 3 of that code to

```
RewriteBase /movies_world/
```

you should be set.